# How to mount my harddrive in easeUS

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to fix my lost partition in EaseUS. I can se the partition in the manager, but I am not able to make it show in my Explorer/computer. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide answers to [well-asked questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). A part of asking a good question is doing some research before you ask, and letting us know what you already tried. Please update your question so that it shows that you put in some effort before posting your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a drive letter to your particular partition.

Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> type `diskmgmt.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

From there select your volume, right click it, and from the context menu Change Drive Letter and Paths.

Hit Change, Assign the following drive letter, select a drive letter and click OK.